# How to take phone numbers after sending message to them - whats app intent

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, whatsapp

I have a button in my app that opens the Whatsapp Intent.
After selecting contacts, the user will send a message to all selected contact.
I want to take all the contacts the user sent a message to and save it in the app.
How should I access the numbers?
There is any getPhoneNumber function after whats app intent is closed?

There is my function to send a message :

```
public void onClickWhatsApp(View view) {

    PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
    try {

        Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        waIntent.setType("text/plain");
        String text = "YOUR TEXT HERE";

        PackageInfo info=pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        //Check if package exists or not. If not then code 
        //in catch block will be called
        waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

        waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Share with"));

   } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
   }  
}
```

Comment: "There is any getPhoneNumber function after whats app intent is closed?" -- no.

Comment: @CommonsWare so maybe another way to do that according to my function?

Comment: My guess is that you would need to get a job with Facebook. WhatsApp has no API that I am aware of. I certainly hope that WhatsApp does not expose contact information to third-party developers without an API.